# Ubuntu 16.04 Install - No "Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu" Option

Tags: 16.04, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 from USB on a new dell laptop shipped with Windows.  When I go through the install process, I never see the screen that has the options for automatic partitioning, such as "Erase disk and install Ubuntu", instead I am taken directly to the manual partitioning screen.

When I manually partition, I get a partitioning failed error message (tried several times including following [these steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)).

I can't install Ubuntu at all with this issue, does anyone know why this would occur and how I can get around it?

Comment: I would investigate what's wrong with your disk partitions. Not much you can do until you understand *why* the system is telling you that there is a problem.

Comment: Start by disabling the fast startup featute in Windows and shutdown prior to trying the installer again.

Comment: @user535733 How do I know there's something wrong with my disk partitions?  How do I investigate what's wrong with them?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I tried that and the behavior is still the same.

Comment: You know there is something wrong with your disk partitions because 1) The Ubuntu Installer does not recognize them, and 2) The manual installer is giving you "partitioning failed" errors. How to investigate the issue is a wholly different question than the one you asked. AskUbuntu is a one-question/many answer format. You must change the question, or open a new question.

Comment: If you can boot Windows use its own tools to check the partitions (reboot needed for the Windows system partition).

Comment: @user535733 You haven't answered my question at all yet. How to investigate the issue is not a wholly different question.  My question is how to solve the issue, so how to investigate it is one step in the answer to this very question.

Comment: They didn't intend to answer (yet). Comments aren't answers, they're suggestions, requests for additional info, troubleshooting steps, etc.

Comment: have you solved this?  my own two cents is that @user535733 has no idea what he's talking about.  it's a new laptop.  there's nothing wrong with the disk partitions.  i'm experiencing the same issue on my new dell laptop.

Comment: maybe [this](https://gist.github.com/jaderabbit/572c3f91c7ab1424fc6d39e0e91344e9) will help?

Comment: fwiw, the link in my previous comment solved the issue for me.

Comment: @dbliss I did end up solving it by tinkering around with the BIOS settings.  However, since I was doing a fair amount of trial and error, I wasn't sure exactly what solved it or if it would be helpful for anyone else, so I didn't post it. (There was of course nothing wrong with my partitions.)